# Is it possible to use Autodesk Forge to get the file activity log for Autodesk Construction Cloud Docs models?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to use Autodesk Forge to extract the log of activities (named "File Activities") for models stored in Autodesk Construction Cloud Docs. An example of the information is attached as an image below. I have so far been unable to find anything in the Forge Documentation, other than extracting the file attributes and last modified information.

Is it possible to extract the file activities? If so, what is the best way for me to proceed?

[File Activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8CEv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no API exposed for the activities functionality.  I will log a wish.